# User Input to change what twitch channel is displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, twitch

I'm not the best coder when it comes to doing something like this so I am asking for help, I've tried searching and couldn't find a solution that worked so sorry if this is really basic or not possible at all.

I have a simple page that loads up twitch with a predefined channel and that channel can only be changed if you manually input the channel name into the code. The channel name is defined where it says "channelnamegoeshere" - if I changed that to channel123 it would load the twitch stream for that channel.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Twitch Cinema</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: black">

<script src= "http://player.twitch.tv/js/embed/v1.js"></script>
<div align="center" id="{PLAYER_DIV_ID}"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
            var options = {
                width: 1600,
                height: 900,
                channel: "{channelnamegoeshere}",
                //video: "{VIDEO_ID}"
            };
            var player = new Twitch.Player("{PLAYER_DIV_ID}", options);
            player.setVolume(0.5);
        </script><!-- <div align="center">
        <iframe frameborder="0" 
            scrolling="no" 
            id="chat_embed" 
            src="http://www.twitch.tv/esgtour/chat" 
            height="350" 
            width="1600">
        </iframe>
        </div>--></body>
</html>
```

Now, what I would like help with, is if it is possible to have it so that when the page loads the user is prompted for input to which they type in the channel name and it then proceeds to load that channel instead.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is totally possible! You can make a function which get's the ID from a form or modal or any other mode of input that you want and return it and then instantiate Twitch with that config object.

Here's a rough example:

```
 function getIdFromUser() {
   // do something here to get the ID from the user
   // example:
   var id = prompt('Type in the twitch ID');
   return id;
 }

 var options = {
      width: 1600,
      height: 900,
      channel: getIdFromUser();
      //video: "{VIDEO_ID}"
 };
 var player = new Twitch.Player("{PLAYER_DIV_ID}", options);
 player.setVolume(0.5);
```